# Mantra to see Lord Hanuman

Tags: mantras, identification-request, hanuman

Is this a mantra by which Lord Hanuman can be seen?
Mantra-कालतंतु कारेचरन्ति एनर मरिष्णु,
निर्मुक्तेर कालेत्वम अमरिष्णु।।

Comment: Are you seeking references from scriptures?

Comment: I just want to know if the above mantra and it's purpose is correct or not. I got this mantra from internet and there is a interesting story associated with it.

Comment: Usually after mantra siddhi the deity gives darshan to the aspirant. If it is this easy then it becomes hard to believe isn't it? @Ram

Comment: @Rickross:yes it is very difficult to believe- conditions of the mantra are- Lord Hanuman had suggested that it would only work when the person who chants it is aware of his/her soul's relationship with Him. He had also announced that within 980 meters from the place where this mantra is chanted, there should not be any human being who does not meet the first condition. Otherwise, the mantra won't work.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense .. these requirements make the procedure difficult to accomplish @Ram

Comment: @Ram what does the condition "Hanuman had suggested that it would only work when the person who chants it is aware of his/her soul's relationship with Him "mean ?

Comment: Why do you wish to see him if I may ask?

Comment: @Rickross: I am not sure it is easy or difficult. Just want to know if the mantra is authentic or not.

Comment: @Mythomaster Sanchit: your soul is the eternal servant of God. Servitude can be in form of parental relationship, lover relationship, like friends or relatives. Be it Krishna as per Gita or Hanuman. God is one but has different Roops. Complete Samparpan to God and awareness that u r not independent. I guess that is the soul's relationship to Hanuman.

Comment: @Wikash_ 5: no particular reason, just want to see..

Comment: Okay @Ram .. I do not know about the mantra. But it must be authentic.

Comment: Please let me know if you see him!

Comment: @Wikash_ sure. If you see him, you can tell me